# show image in Jlabel using Image icon

Tags: java

I'm using a Jlabel imageIcon to display my image
when I set the path of the image in a local machine it works perfectly but when I change the path to an image which is located in an other machine(NAS Server in my case) nothing displays and yet no problem is raised  can any one help me.
here is a code snippet:

```
ImageIcon imic= new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(path).getImage().getScaledInstance(imgshow.getWidth(), imgshow.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
                imgshow.setIcon(imic);
```

Any help I'll be thankful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said "NAS Server in my case". Could we assume it's a normal "Samba" share ?

Comment: Sorry but didn't get what you mean by 'normal Samba share'! would you explain please

Comment: I meant that you don't tell us which protocol you're refering to when you say "an image which is located in an other machine(NAS Server in my case)". So I assumed it was Samba share (and that should work). Is it more explanative ?

Comment: still didn't get you're point clearly but but as protocol i'm using TCP/IP and the path to the image is something like "\\NAS\Folder\test.png"

Comment: Ok, as you showed, it's a samba share. [SMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block)

 I've tested here and have no problem with for instance :

`lblIcon.setIcon(new ImageIcon("\\\\192.168.1.54\\home\\al4bedo.jpg"));`

Comment: Thank you so much it was so helpful the problem was in the "\\" at the beginning of the path.